# passing lambda to a lambda callback parameter

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, c++17, type-erasure

I am using c++14 and I have a use case where I have to effectively do this:

```
template <typename F>
void foo (F&& fun)
{
    auto l = []()->int
    {
        return 20;
    };

    fun(l);
}

int main ()
{
    auto l = [] (auto& a)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello function: " << a() << std::endl;
        // 'a' has to be copied to a queue optionally
    };

    foo(l);
}
```

But the `foo()` in-turn calls a million function - which uses the callback '`fun`'. I cannot put all the code in header file. The simplest way to keep the definition of `foo()` and the called functions in dot cpp file might be to change `foo()` to

```
void foo (std::function< void(std::function<int(void)>) > fun)
```

But this is too inefficient, I dont want any memory allocation. Here there will be many, one of the creating the '`fun`' and then for every call to '`fun(...)`'. Now the outer std::function can be optimized by using something like the function_ref mentioned here. 
https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html#fn_view_impl

But inner std::function, cannot be because it has to be 'optionally' copied to a queue. Now how can I make this work without a memory allocation - as close to the performance as using the template. [ One way is to have something like the std::function with a fixed internal storage.] But I have a feeling there exists a way by throwing more templates to achieve what I want. Or some way to change the interface to have more of less same effect.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo • seems this question may be in your court.

Comment: Your lambda is captureless so you can use the implicit conversion to pass a function pointer instead of `std::function` to get rid of the allocation.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Well in the real use, its not captureless. I just kept it simple of the example.

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question in the question?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but maybe it can be to some help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <memory>

struct lambdaHolderBase {
    virtual int operator()() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct lambdaHolder : lambdaHolderBase {
    lambdaHolder(T tf) : t(tf) {}
    T& t;
    int operator()() override { return t(); }
};

template <typename F>
void foo (F&& fun)
{
    auto l = []()->int
    {
        return 20;
    };
    lambdaHolder<decltype(l)> l2(l);

    fun(l2);
}

int main ()
{
    auto l = [] (auto& a)
    {
        static std::deque<lambdaHolderBase*> queue;
        std::cout << "Hello function: " << a() << std::endl;
        queue.emplace_back( &a );
        // 'a' has to be copied to a queue optionally
    };

    foo(l);
}
```

Comment: This does not look correct. Cannot save the stack variable address in queue. Otherwise we will have to allocate the lambdaHolder in heap. In which case we can use std::function itself.

Comment: You are right. This should however require less heap space to be allocated, especially if the lambda has state and the initial lambda object is kept alive until the queue has been used.